# How to make fixed height cell on uitableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

So I want to make timeline content like instagram, I'm using custom cell on my uitableview. My problem is I already set the cell height to 345 on the storyboard but I get cell table like below:

[image: celltablescreenshot]

and here is my custom cell on storyboard:

[image: storyboardss]

How can I fix it, so I can get the result like on my storyboard?

Comment: Mark Custom Height option from IB. And set Cell Height from Table View Properties.

Comment: i have also told you the same thing which natasha posted in answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason that you are having this issue is you have probably set your Custom tableview cell's row height to 345 but that is not set as custom while your UITableview's row height is less than 345. So, what you need to do is go to storyboard and select the Table(UITableview) and set its row height to the maximum possible row height.

[image]

Let's assume that you are going to have two different kind of row heights. One with 345 and another with 325. As 325<345, you set your tableview's row height to 345.

[image]

Now, select the custom tableview cell and make its row height as custom and set that to either 345 or 325. In your case, it will be 345.

[image]

It should be good now.

However, more appropriate way when you have different cell size would be to use the delegate method for row height specification.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if(indexPath.row==0){
      return 345;
   }
   else if(indexPath.row==1){
      return 325;
   }
   else{
      return 300; //a default size if the cell index path is anything other than the 1st or second row.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this `delegate` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 345
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your UITableViewController subclass, set `self.tableView.rowHeight = 345`. Might be a bug with storyboard heights not being translated.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra `self.tableView?.rowHeight = 345`

Comment: May be you haven't created an IBOutlet for your tableview. The above code should only work if you have an outlet connecting to your UITableview and named as tableview. Then in your viewdidload, you could have accessed the rowHeight with self.tableView.rowHeight.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Table View Cell height here.

[image]

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Select Tableview from Storyboard. and set the Row height.